# Send data from a external class in Swift. Music App

Tags: ios, swift

I have been researching over and over again the way to store data depending of the choice of the users and to show it in a UILabel or wherever in different views.

It would be something like this:[image: Picture]

1. First users choose an instrument
2. In a second view user choose the style of the melody
3. And in a third one they all can choose the duration of it.
4. With that a screen is deployed with three changeable labels depending of the preview options which have been chosen.

   a. How we can store the information chosen?
   b. How to show the information in the lastVC?

Comment: This is pretty broad, and multiple questions in one tend not to work well here, can you try to break up your question into single, defined problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to do this you can use a Facade pattern. to give you an exemple:
you can create a MusicFacade.swift. All the infirmation that you want to store like instrument , style of melody ... are stores in statique variable:

```
class MusicFacade {

  static var _instrument: String =""
  static var _stryleMelody: String = " "
  static var _duree : Int = 0
}
```

then when you want to store the information that the user enter you juste use:

```
MusicFacade._instrument = "Piano"
```

in you controller code

[To have a look on iOS pattern](http://www.raywenderlich.com/86477/introducing-ios-design-patterns-in-swift-part-1)
Hope it 'll help you

Comment: Thanks Edgar. I'll take a look, but it looks very useful